# QLIK Sense radar chart I need to show two dimensions on same Radar Chart, e.g. employee skills and employee interests

Tags: qliksense, radar-chart

I do not seem to find a way to show two dimensions e.g. employee skills and interest as shown on the image generated with python.

SAMPLE CHART
This chart was generated from Python to ilustrate what I need to achieve using QLIK Sense radar chart https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNh7S.png

SAMPLE DATA
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdb2F.png

Answer (score 0):

For radar chart you need to have 2 dimensions and 1 measure.
To have such view, you need to have data in this similar structure:

```
load * inline [
two_dimensions, values, points
skills, python,5
skills, sql,3
skills, qlik,3
skills, pipelines,5
skills, statistics,3
interests, python,2
interests, sql,2
interests, qlik,5
interests, pipelines,5
interests, statistics,5];
```

[and from this just create a chart in QLIK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGJLc.png)